# How to get the link of click promotion in appStore

Tags: ios, app-store

The promotion item in appStore can click to open app.

#### How to open specific page from that `click`, and how to get the link from that `click` ?

I know the `Deep link` things, but I didn't find any page mentioned the real link of that `$40` item, which I can test more times by past into Safari, and with my debug version.

[The left image]: What I want is click `$40` of the Subscription item in appStore, then open my page in app to show the purchase page of app.

#### Why I want is to know the link when I clicked the buy button in promotion item.

Because if i click it in appStore, it will make my phone to install the app and replace my `debug version` on my device.  That I can't event test it once in `debug mode`.

[The right image]: When I debug the app with Xcode, and click `$40` of the Subscription item in appStore, it will install the app, and replace my debug version.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For normal processing you don't need to worry about a URL or deep links.

When the user initiates the purchase from the App Store and opens your app, the purchase information is delivered to the [`paymentQueue(_:shouldAddStorePayment:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransactionobserver/2877502-paymentqueue)  method in your `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`. This is another reason that one of the first things your app should do when it launches is establish an `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`

In this method you have access to the payment request and the product and you can configure your app UI appropriately as well as accept or deny the purchase request.

You can [test the in-app purchase promotion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/testing_promoted_in-app_purchases) using an `itms-services://` url.

Send yourself an email with a link `itms-services://?action=purchaseIntent&bundleId=com.example.app&productIdentifier=product_name` where you substitute your app's bundle Id and your IAP product identifier.  Open the email on your device and click on the link.

Comment: Yes,  I have think of the purchase delegate, but the requirement force me to handle purchase thing only when I open the purchase page. Which means I should not handle subscription things from purchase delegate just after app open, I know it’s normal way, but maybe not my case. Let me have a look.Thanks.

Comment: I have checked that, I have add shouldAddStorePayment delegate func, and open a url which will open my purchase page, but it never happened. Didn’t know which part is missing

Comment: Do you establish your payment queue observer in `didFinishLaunching`?  You really must do this.  You cannot wait until the payment view is opened - "Your app should add the transaction observer at app launch to ensure that your app will receive payment queue notifications as soon as possible." https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/setting_up_the_transaction_observer_for_the_payment_queue

Comment: Once you get the delegate call you can navigate to the purchase page to present the relevant information - You can pass the payment and product details to this page.  I wouldn't be going via a URL; you can manipulate your app's view hierarchy directly

Comment: how do you debug this event, since click in AppStore will replace the debug version of app

Comment: Thank you ~ Your answer looks correct for me, I'll test it later, but mark it as answer first.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how to open the promoted app from the source app and or redirect to app store page? And open another from the source app? If so, you can use `Deep linking` and `openURL`.

> `Deep link` to open your other app from your source app with
> URL Scheme `scheme://resource`
>
> and
>
> `openURL` to open and show the app in App Store using `itms-apps://`

Comment: no,  usually click buy item of the promote item will open app.
I want to open app and  open the page which displayed purchase items in app.

Comment: then, `Deep linking` is your way to go. That way you can open the app and add the resource to parse. That way you can tell which page and info to show on your other app.

Comment: I know how to open specific page by `Deep linking`,  I just didn't know how the link of click the buy button in promotion item.

Comment: What I want is to know the link when I clicked the `buy` button in promotion item.
so I can do some test like open this kind of link in Safari and do several test in `Debug mode`.  Which because if i click it in appStore, it will make my phone to install  the app and replace my `debug version` on my device.

Comment: I see, that might be impossible because that is already in the 'App Store' and that was sandboxed unless apple allows it.

Comment: Yes, the key point is to find the url format of that link 'schema://host/path?parametes`,  just wonder where can I found that.

Comment: @JerryZhou See [this](https://medium.com/wolox/ios-deep-linking-url-scheme-vs-universal-links-50abd3802f97) for more information about deep linking and universal links.

Comment: I know the deep link feature, I just want know the link of this  $40 button of the Subscription item in appStore.